# My tunnel bore has corrupted, what can I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My tunnel bore (frame motors, CC chunk loaders) stopped. When I went to investigate, it crashed the server. Then, every time I logged in again, it crashed the server. I only escaped by editing my coordinates in my `player.dat`. Is this situation recoverable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a world edit tool and take it out. This happens when the frames/block breakers/miners/etc come accross mod blocks that they don't know what to do with. Some new worldgen might not be fully functional in the forge dictionary and cause things to not cooperate.

Solutions: World edit or rollback